# set session variable with fetch array PDO, not working

Tags: php, arrays, session, pdo, fetch

Coding, as I've been learning, is about little details, and I'm missing something because I have the following code:

```
public function login() {
    if ($_POST) {
      $logdb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kiko', 'kiko', 'pass');
      $logdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $stmt = $logdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM usreg WHERE email=:email AND password=:pass");
      $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST['email']);
      $stmt->bindParam(":pass", $_POST['password']);
      $stmt->execute();
      $loged = $stmt->fetch();
      $atributes = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if ($loged) {
         session_start();
         $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
         $_SESSION["id"] = $atributes->id;
         $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
         $_SESSION["group"] = $atributes->group;
         $_SESSION["firstname"] = $atributes->firstname;
         $_SESSION["lastname"] = $atributes->lastname;
         $_SESSION["phone"] = $atributes->phone;
         $_SESSION["mobile"] = $atributes->mobile;
         $_SESSION["adress"] = $atributes->adress;
         $_SESSION["city"] = $atributes->city;
         $_SESSION["country"] = $atributes->country;
      } else {
          echo 'wrong login try again';
        }
      } else {
          echo '<form name="login" action="" method="POST">
      Email: <br />
      <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
      Password: <br />
      <input type="password" name="password"/><br />
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <a href="register.php">Register</a></form>';
      }
  }
```

and everything works well except the part where I'm registering globals. What I'm trying to do is set the global session the details from the fetch array atributes, I tried with:

```
 $atributes = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

but the result is the same, and I changed the email from array to `POST` and it works because when I do:

```
echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

It works, but the fetch is not passing the details to the other session globals. What should I put in there to sucess what I'm trying to do can you guys help me? Do I need another kind of prepared statement? Is it missing results because I'm making the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you fetching twice? Once for $loged and another for $atributes

I assume the username/password combination will be unique, so you'll only get one result from your SQL query. That means when you call fetch again, you'll get nothing.

Perhaps you want:

```
    //$loged = $stmt->fetch();
    $atributes = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if ($atributes) {
        session_start();

        $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
        $_SESSION["id"] = $atributes->id;
```

Also, make sure you use [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when dealing with passwords!

Comment: Use `FETCH_OBJ` instead of `FETCH_ASSOC` since the code populating the session is relying on `->`...

Comment: I tryed with FETCH_OBJ before but maybe i did something wrong cause it wasnt working, right now i just deleted everything and put like you said and it is working, thank you very much my friend ;)